# Laravel 4 : Cookies for unique visitor count

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4

I am creating a simple blog in which a user can **add, update and view posts**. I have implemented the **views count functionality in the post that shows the number of views on the post**. For that, what I did is:

1. Created an event listener:

   `Event::listen('post.viewed', 'PostHandler@updatePostViewsAction');`
2. Created the `PostHandler` and `updatePostViewsAction`

   ```
   class PostHandler
   {
       public function handle()
       {
           // 
       }

       public function updatePostViewsAction( $post )
       {
           // Update view counter of post
           $post->views_count = $post->views_count + 1;
           $post->save();
       }
   }
   ```

This is **working fine and the views count is succesfuly being updated.** But later on I decided **to make the views to be uniquely counted.** For this, I have **tried using the cookies** i.e. create a **cookie on users computer,** whenever he views a post and **increment the `views_count`** . If the **users comes back again** and views the post again, check **if there is a cookie** available, if it is available **then don't increment the `views_count`**, **otherwise increment that**. Below is, how I have implemented this:

```
class PostHandler
{
    public function handle()
    {
        // 
    }

    public function updatePostViewsAction( $post )
    {
        if ( !Cookie::get('post_viewed') ) {
            // Update view counter of post
            $post->views_count = $post->views_count + 1;
            $post->save();
            Cookie::forever('post_viewed', true);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, as **the views_count is getting incremented each and every time**. Can anyone please tell me, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the cookie is indeed created ? Use your browser's developer tools to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to save a cookie with Laravel, you are required to send it to the response. However, you can workaround it by sending the cookie to the queue.

```
public function updatePostViewsAction( $post )
{
    if ( !Cookie::get('post_viewed') ) {
        // Update view counter of post
        $post->views_count = $post->views_count + 1;
        $post->save();
        // Create a cookie before the response and set it for 30 days
        Cookie::queue('post_viewed', true, 60 * 24 * 30);
    }
}
```

Source from Laravel Docs http://laravel.com/docs/requests#cookies:

> **Queueing A Cookie For The Next Response**
>
> If you would like to set a cookie before a response has been created, use the Cookie::queue() method. The cookie will automatically be attached to the final response from your application.